# Does item quality decrease over time?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In *Counter-Strike: Global Offensive*, I have an "AUG Hot Rod: Factory New" Skin. Each skin in CS:GO has it's own quality, and each quality looks different (Ex. Well-worn may have paint peeled off).

If I use my Factory New AUG in CS:GO, will the quality decrease, or will it stay the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This guide says no:

> As you can see, Factory New has the freshest looking paint job out of
>   any of the item exteriors. **The item exteriors will not degrade over
>   time**. They are simply another variation of weapon finishes.

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=169698044

Answer (score 3):

They do not, the weapon condition stays the same, and does not degrade over time.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, they do! Each weapon you get from a drop or crate will degrade and wear over time.

Comment: This is wrong.. they don't degrade